# Cognito user pool: admin-update-user-attributes: errors on trying to update default attribute: "email"

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

```
AdminUpdateUserAttributesRequest request = new AdminUpdateUserAttributesRequest();
        AttributeType data = new AttributeType();
        data.setName("email");
        data.setValue(email);
        request.withUserAttributes(data);
        request.withUserAttributes(
                new AttributeType().withName("email").withValue(email),
                new AttributeType().withName("email_verified").withValue("true")
        );
        request.withUsername(userName);
        request.withUserPoolId(userPoolID);
        cognitoClient.adminUpdateUserAttributes(request);
```

I am using above code to update email of the existing cognito pool user. Code works for the user pool created in "eu-west-2" region, but I have created a new new pool in "eu-north-1".

For the newly created user pool I am getting error as "Invalid user attributes: email: Attribute cannot be updated - AWSCognitoIdentityProvider". I have cross checked both User pool attributes, I can't able to find what I have missed while creating this user pool.

Any ideas, why **Cognito is not allowing me to update default "email" attribute value of the existing users**

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly identified the problem and found that Cognito released beta version of User pool in region "eu-north-1". So I have again changed the User Pool location to "eu-west-2", nothing else changed. Works fine in this region